# Devise - redirecting to resend confirmation instruction page after confirmation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using `Ruby 2.0`, `Rails 4.0` and `Devise 3.0.3`

I have changed my app to new domain, so I changed the host in `development.rb` file as below,

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'xxxxx.com' }
```

After this,

After signup, when I click confirmation link in mail, my account get confirmed but it takes me to **resend cofirmation instruction page**.

This is my after confirmation path,

```
  def after_confirmation_path_for(resource_or_scope)
   new_order_path
  end
```

I want to go to `new_order_path`

Where am I making mistake, should I change it in any other place?

Please some one help me in this.

**Note**: in my old domain it was working fine.

Comment: **so I changed the host in `development.rb`** for your locally. For production, you should config at `production.rb`

Comment: @anonymousxxx are we even talking about an issue in production? otherwise it should be evident that changing something in `development.rb` does not change any production setting. but who knows...

Comment: @phoet IDEM with you, but I think like that because OP replace old domai with a new domain (although he didn't say in the production), and I just tell the OP about it. I'll see..

Comment: @Abhiram Can you post apps log?

Comment: is the user already confirmed before you click the link?

Comment: i have also changed prodcution.rb but no use :(

Comment: to be sure you are sending the email try test it in development using [mailcatcher gem](http://mailcatcher.me/)

Comment: Did this ever solved your issue? Actually I'm having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Usually this occurs due to session persistence.

Once you send the invitation, sign out of your website (I assume you have a link "sign out" at the top of your page).

Then view the confirmation mail that was sent and click on the link. This way when the browser opens the page it will use the token in the url of the confirmation link to authenticate the new user.